# systemd fails running ssh

Tags: ssh, systemd

The command from `ExcecStart` works from the commandline, *but not as service*. What am I missing?

Tried adding `USER`,`GROUP` to the service. Without `Environment` as well. No success.

`cat .config/systemd/user/mysync.service`

```
[Unit]
Description = Rsync

[Service]
Type = oneshot
ExecStart = /usr/bin/rsync -avuP raspi:/home/pi/tmp/ /home/foo/Documents/pi/tmp/
Environment = USER=foo
Environment = HOME=/home/foo

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

`[foo@x org]$ systemctl --user daemon-reload`

`[foo@x org]$ systemctl --user restart mysync.service`

```
Oct 06 14:10:07 x systemd[548]: Starting Rsync...
Oct 06 14:10:07 x rsync[15444]: Permission denied, please try again.
Oct 06 14:10:07 x rsync[15444]: Permission denied, please try again.
Oct 06 14:10:07 x rsync[15444]: root@pi: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

`cat /home/foo/.ssh/config`

```
Host raspi
HostName 192.168.123.123
User root
```

I'm using [gpg as ssh key](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#Using_a_PGP_key_for_SSH_authentication).

Comment: At least on a regular Arch Linux (no Pi at hand, unfortunately), I couldn't reproduce your issue. You may try adding `-e 'ssh -vvv'` as an option to `rsync` in your `ExecStart` key, letting `ssh` emit verbose logging information, and then look at it with `journalctl --user -u mysync.service`. Similarly, you may also add `-vvv` as an option to `rsync` to the same command, to see its verbose output too.

Comment: I do not see you defining any key for logging into the raspberry pi or providing a password?

Comment: I have no complete understanding of how it works, but I'd guess the systemd service environment is missing the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable, which would tell `ssh` where to find the agent that has your private key(s). You should probably add more information on your setup - e.g. are you using `ssh-agent`? What is the value `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in a shell opened in your user's session? Is `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` set by `gpg-agent` instead? - but I'm not really sure of what the relevant elements could be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the private key file:

```
rsync -options -e "ssh -i /path/to/private-key-file" /source /destination
```

Comment: Thank you. Is my understanding correct, that systemd requires additional effort to handle ssh keys? The commandline seems having no problem finding my ssh config (added in question)